# Is a question about pranks off topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I asked this question - [My colleague often shuts down my machine through the LAN - how do I prevent it?](https://superuser.com/questions/717192/my-colleague-often-shuts-down-my-machine-through-the-lan-how-do-i-prevent-it)?  regarding one prank by my colleague and the prevention technique,

And this [comment](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/920511?noredirect=1) made me to think on another question,what were the pranks which you played with the colleague. If i ask will it be off topic?

I thought to ask the question since it will come up with some tricky parts of Windows and Linux where users play around with and it will help us new stuff and prevention,will the community take it as followup question or it will be closed as off topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions asking for a list of pranks, how to do a prank or generally in the mind of "What's a good prank to pull?" are off topic and out of scope. They are not constructive, too broad and more suitable to a discussion forum.

These would be closed.

In the past, these type of questions have been asked, but they have also been closed and deleted.

Answer (score 7):

> What were the pranks which you played with the colleague. If i ask will it be off topic?

From [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers:

So yes, your question is  yet another polling question & will be closed